# Rerender map after click on button - openlayers-3

Tags: openlayers-3

I am trying to re-render the map after a click on my button, because I change the base-map from source.OSM({layer:'hot'}) to ol.source.MapQuest({layer: 'sat'}).

I am trying to do it as following:

```
var map = new ol.Map({
      target: 'map',
      controls: [],
      layers: layers,
      view: new ol.View({
        center: ol.proj.transform(lonlat, 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857'),
        zoom: 14
      })
    });

var layers = [
new ol.layer.Tile({
    style: 'none',
    source: baseLayer
}),
new ol.layer.Group({
    style: 'leegstand',
    visible: false,
    layers: [
        new ol.layer.Tile({
            source: baseLayer
        }),
        borderObject,
        leegstandObject
    ]
}), ..etc

$('.base-sat').click(function(){
  baseLayer = new ol.source.MapQuest({layer: 'sat'});
  //ol.source.tile.Changed()
  //layers.getSource().changed();
  //mapRender();
});
```

I tried a lot, but it wont refresh my map...

Answer (score 0):

Use [`map.renderSync()`](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.9.0/apidoc/ol.Map.html#renderSync) or [`map.render()`](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.9.0/apidoc/ol.Map.html#render) to trigger a re-render. `renderSync` should re-render the map synchronously, while `render` triggers a render in the next animation frame.

Though it seems that you are not actually changing anything, from the code in question. In the click handler, you assign a new `Source` to the `baseLayer` variable. But you don't seem to be modifying any layer in the map. What you probably want is to set the new source to the layer, using

```
// layer is assumed to reference the layer you wish to change
layer.setSource(new ol.source.MapQuest({layer: 'sat'});
```

Comment: Thank you! And what kind of event triggers the next animation frame? Im not familiar with that term.

Comment: And is it also possible to rerender just one layer? If there are multiple layers loaded?

Comment: About animation frames: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame

Comment: I tried to use the map.renderSync after a click on a button, but it does not seem to reload?